# Windows: Elixir phoenix MIX_ENV=prod : The term is not recognized

Tags: windows, powershell, elixir, phoenix-framework

Just started to learn elixir and phoenix framework. for the most part it going well. However when I want to run ecto.create on my production configs, I get an error in my cmd & powershell that MIX_ENV=prod : The term is not recognized. Just in general though MIX_ENV=Xyz doesn't work for me.

I've made a fresh new phoenix project to see if it was a compile problem. wasn't that.

Working on windows.

> MIX_ENV=prod : The term 'MIX_ENV=prod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
>   path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MIX_ENV=prod:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any thoughts what would make a important function stop working?

phoenix,1.1.4

Elixir 1.2.1

Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MIX_ENV` is an environment variable and you just need to set it. Powershell does that differently than a *nix shell, so the examples that show putting `MIX_ENV=prod` in line with the mix command won't work.

Use `$env:MIX_ENV="prod"` to set the environment variable and then call the rest of the mix command line.

Comment: And if you're using the cmd shell you'll want to run "Set MIX_ENV=prod"  NB: the environment variable will only persist for the duration of the session.  That is when you exit the console,  the environment variable will be lost.